# Java printing stretched on Konica - Minolta PagePro printers

Tags: java, printing

I am using JasperReports to print from my Java application. All the prints were OK for all costumers for quite a bit of time, but recently we have installed the software for couple of costumers that all have Konica Minolta PagePro 1200 or 1350W printers. And all those costumers get the same result - the printing is "stretched" - as if I printed A4 report on A5 paper. Except that I am printing A4 on A4 and on all other printers it works fine.

Does anyone have any idea what might be the cause?

This questions seems similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15854722/jasper-report-printing-stretched but the workaround presented there (messing with printer paper size etc.) did not lead to desired result.

Here is an example of the print:

[image: Example print]

And this is what the print should look like (there are slighlty different data, but I guess the problem is clear)

[image: Desired print]

Thanks for any suggestions.

EDIT:

The issue can be reproduced with a simple direct call to printing API:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.print.Book;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
import java.awt.print.Paper;
import java.awt.print.Printable;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;

/**
 *
 * @author MaCe
 */
public class PrintTest {

    static Printable printable = new Printable() {
        @Override
        public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException {
            Graphics2D grx = (Graphics2D)graphics;
            grx.drawLine(20,20, getPageWidth() / 2, 20);
            return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
        }

    };
    protected static int getPageWidth() {
        //width of A4 in 1/72 of inches
        return 595;
    }

    protected static int getPageHeight() {
        //height of A4 in 1/72 of inches
        return 842;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws PrinterException {
        Frame f = new Frame();
        f.show();

        //Build a buggy print job using PrinterJob class
        PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

        /**
     * Fix for bug ID 6255588 from Sun bug database
     */
        try {
            printJob.setPrintService(printJob.getPrintService());
        } catch (PrinterException e) {
        }

        PageFormat pageFormat = printJob.defaultPage();
        Paper paper = pageFormat.getPaper();

        printJob.setJobName("Buggy output");

        pageFormat.setOrientation(PageFormat.PORTRAIT);
        paper.setSize(getPageWidth() , getPageHeight());
        paper.setImageableArea(
                0,
                0, getPageWidth(), getPageHeight());

        pageFormat.setPaper(paper);

        Book book = new Book();
        book.append(printable, pageFormat, 1);
        printJob.setPageable(book);

        if (printJob.printDialog()) {
            printJob.print();
        }

        //Build a good print job using PrintJob class
        PrintJob pjob = f.getToolkit().getPrintJob(f, "Good output", null);
        if (pjob!=null) {
            Graphics g = pjob.getGraphics();
            g.drawLine(20, 20, pjob.getPageDimension().width / 2, 20);
            pjob.end();
        }

        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Now this code produces two prints that on most printers both print a line from the top left corner of the paper to the middle of the paper. However on the aforementioned printers the first print creates a thick line across the whole paper (200% scale) - the second variant is however OK even on Minolta printers.

Seems like a Java bug, since all other programs print normally with the printer. The bug was accepted by Sun, but closed as they could not get their hands on the correct printer (https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-804159)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround to the problem. The solution is to scale the graphics to half before printing. This is not easy to do with JasperReports, as the graphics object is not exposed anywhere. However, my app uses @AspectJ so I managed to fiddle with the graphics through a custom aspect:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;


@Aspect
public class JRMinoltaAspect {        

    @Before("execution(int net.sf.jasperreports.engine.print.JRPrinterAWT.print(java.awt.Graphics, java.awt.print.PageFormat , int )) && args(g, pf, ..)")
    public void scalePrint(Graphics g, PageFormat pf){
        if(pf.getOrientation() == PageFormat.LANDSCAPE){
            g.translate(0, (int)pf.getHeight() / 2 );
        }
        ((Graphics2D)g).scale(0.5, 0.5);        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your platform windows/mac/linux?

I've had trouble with printing with label printers when the print job's media hint did not communicate fully through to the driver.  Its actually very similar to your problem, stretched prints, skipped pages etc,.

I dont know if you have code to modify, but we had to switch to System Printing instead of Java Printing.  Then with the System Printing settings, (windows spooler in my case), I had to create a printer with the exact driver settings needed to print properly.  Its rarely anything you can really do in JasperReports other than specify the width/height/orientation.

I assume your report prints fine when saved to PDF, then print from a PDF Viewer.

Comment: Yes, saving as PDF and then printing works well. Could you please elaborate on what "Switching to System Printing to Java Printing" means? A Google search did not reveal anything related... The platform is Windows (both 7 and XP).